# How to run Typescript ES6+ server side via .net core and nodejs using Jering.Javascript.NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, typescript, .net-core, ecmascript-2020

I want to run some TypeScript Code written in ES2020 on Server Side. Currently i have running a ASP.NET Core Application so the idea was to run js via Jering.Javascript.NodeJS and nodejs.

So started with a basic example.

```
var test = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromFileAsync<string>("Scripts/server/modules/hello.ts", args: new object[] {  });
```

hello.ts

```js
module.exports = (callback, x, y) => {  // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
    var result = "test"; // Your javascript logic
    callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
}
```

Works...added some import statemant...

hello.ts

```js
import someFunction from "./some.func";

module.exports = (callback, x, y) => {  // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
    var result = "test"; // Your javascript logic
    callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
}
```

--> "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Nodejs version v16.13.2 and in package.json there is already set

```
 "type": "module"
```

changing to require

hello.ts

```js
const someFunction = require("./some.func")

module.exports = (callback, x, y) => {  // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
    var result = "test"; // Your javascript logic
    callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
}
```

results in "InvocationException: require() of ES Module ... from ... not supported. Instead change the require of some.func.js in ... to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules"

So kind of infinity loop.

By looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136952/can-a-c-sharp-application-communicate-with-node-js-code/60913173#60913173) it seems to be possible but how do i get this running?

Comment: See the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility) take special note of the asterisk on the NodeJS column.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution

1. we have some ES6+ Module which could have itself other import statements.

   ```
    let nodeStart = () => {
        return "ES6+ module";
    }

    export default nodeStart;
   ```
2. use webpack and babel to convert from ES6+ to commonjs

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
    const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = (env, options) => {
        console.log(`Webpack 'mode': ${options.mode}`);
        var isDev = options.mode === 'development';
        return {      
            entry: {            
                'some-module-node': "./Scripts/server-test/some-module.ts",
            },
            output: {
                filename: '[name].js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/server-test"),
                libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
            },         
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.tsx?$/,
                        loader: 'ts-loader',                    
                        exclude: file => (
                            /node_modules/.test(file
                        ))
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: [
                                    ['@babel/preset-env', {
                                        modules: false,
                                        useBuiltIns: 'usage'
                                    }]
                                ]
                            }
                        }                   
                    } 
                ]
            },
            resolve: {
                extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
            },
            target: 'node',      
            devtool: isDev ? "source-map" : undefined,
            plugins: [
                new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
                    typescript: {
                       
                    }
                })
            ]        
        }
    };
```

3. In packages.json create script for webpack und run it.
4. "some-module-node.js" will be generated.
5. use "start-node.js" as entry point for "Jering.Javascript.NodeJS"

   const someModule = require('./some-module-node.js')

   ```
    function start(callback, x) {  // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
        var result = someModule.default()

        callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
    }

    module.exports = start
   ```
6. from .net core run

   ```
     var test = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromFileAsync<string> 
     ("Scripts/server-test/start-node.js", args: new object[] {  });
   ```

*test* will be "ES6+ module"