# Python Multiprocessing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, concurrency, multiprocessing

I am new to Node.js but I have an extensive Python background, and I was wondering how I would achieve the same outcome on Node.js as I would with Python Multiprocessing Pools. I have seen people do this without any outside libraries, so it leads me to believe that it is something native to Node. Every time I try to research this topic, I get some response about Clustering, which is effective on the server side of Node.js, but I am using Node through my command line, for desktop apps. Thanks to all!

Comment: read about `cluster` module here https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/cluster.html , there are also some packages that have nice features, not very familiar with python myself.

Comment: cluster is not useful in desktop nodejs

Comment: i don't think you understand what cluster does in node.js.. `A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take advantage of multi-core systems, the user will sometimes want to launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.` its native to node.js and its as close it can get to multiprocessing..

Answer (score 0):

Node.js base architecture design is one-threaded, but [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) provides a neat approach for taking advantage of multi-core systems for creating TCP and HTTP servers (what you may mean by referring to as *server side of Node.js*).
Cluster module itself, uses [child processes module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to provide its functionality.

*Child processes* module provides functionalities for opening (spawning) other processes and communicating with them. (see [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) for more information on this module's functionalities)

Given above information you have these options for doing multiprocess operations in Node.js:

- Use node's native *child processes* module
- Use various [including non-native tools and] [techniques for IPC (Inter-process communication) in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463945/whats-the-most-efficient-node-js-inter-process-communication-library-method):